# How can I catch an Entity Framework error, report on it and then leave the function with that same exception?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have this code in my application. If the insert fails, I would like to add information about the failure to the `Audit` table. Perhaps the inner exception message from the exception in the note area. Is there a way that I could do this and then still have the procedure exit with that same exception details back to the caller?

```
    [Route("Post")]
    [ValidateModel]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Phrase phrase)
    {
        phrase.StatusId = (int)EStatus.Saved;
        UpdateHepburn(phrase);

        db.Phrases.Add(phrase);

        var audit = new Audit()
        {
            Entity = (int)EEntity.Phrase,
            Action = (int)EAudit.Insert,
            Note = phrase.English,
            UserId = userId,
            Date = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Id = phrase.PhraseId
        };

        db.Audits.Add(audit);

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(phrase);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the original exception and rethrow it afterwards:

```
try
{
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: add to the audit here, also in a try/catch as this might fail as well
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    // rethrow the original exception
    throw;
}
```